# Gluon Client Plugin: Building APK with Jackson and Java Time Module

Tags: java, gluon-mobile, javafx-11

This is the **HelloFX** project from [gluon client samples](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples) project.

I've added a model named '**Person**'.

```
package hellofx;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Person {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private LocalDate dob;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

And added the following dependencies in 'pom.xml':

- jackson-databind
- jackson-datatype-jsr310

And added serialization and deserialization methods in main class.

```
public class HelloFX extends Application {

    private Label parseStatusLabel = new Label("");
    
    private String serializedString = null;

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");
        String javafxVersion = System.getProperty("javafx.version");
        Label label = new Label("Hello, JavaFX " + javafxVersion + ", running on Java " + javaVersion + ".");

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image(HelloFX.class.getResourceAsStream("/hellofx/openduke.png")));
        imageView.setFitHeight(200);
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);

        Button serButton = new Button("Serialize");
        serButton.setOnAction(e -> serialize());

        Button deserButton = new Button("Deserialize");
        deserButton.setOnAction(e -> deserialize());

        VBox root = new VBox(30, imageView, label, serButton, deserButton, parseStatusLabel);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 640, 480);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(HelloFX.class.getResource("styles.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private void serialize() {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setId(1);
        person.setName("John Doe");
        person.setDob(LocalDate.of(1960, 10, 10));

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

        try {
            serializedString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(person);
            parseStatusLabel.setText("Serialization success \n" + serializedString);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            parseStatusLabel.setText("Serialization failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void deserialize() {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

            Person person = mapper.readValue(serializedString, Person.class);
            parseStatusLabel.setText("Deserialization successful > " + person);
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            parseStatusLabel.setText("Deserialization failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            parseStatusLabel.setText("Deserialization failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

I ran it in desktop and it ran fine. Both serialization and deserialization worked.
And then I tried to build APK with **mvn client:build -P android** , it throws the following error event after running **mvn client:runagent**.

```
[Thu Mar 25 10:38:59 IST 2021][INFO] We will now compile your code for aarch64-linux-android. This may take some time.
[Thu Mar 25 10:39:14 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB] [hellofx.hellofx:215]    classlist:   5,873.73 ms,  0.96 GB
[Thu Mar 25 10:39:16 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB] [hellofx.hellofx:215]        (cap):     288.58 ms,  0.96 GB
[Thu Mar 25 10:39:17 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB] [hellofx.hellofx:215]        setup:   2,968.21 ms,  0.96 GB
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:25 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB] [hellofx.hellofx:215]     (clinit):   1,142.49 ms,  3.74 GB
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:25 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB] [hellofx.hellofx:215]   (typeflow):  30,888.81 ms,  3.74 GB
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:25 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB] [hellofx.hellofx:215]    (objects):  28,773.30 ms,  3.74 GB
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:25 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB] [hellofx.hellofx:215]   (features):   5,209.44 ms,  3.74 GB
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB] [hellofx.hellofx:215]     analysis:  68,730.14 ms,  3.74 GB
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB] Warning: Aborting stand-alone image build. Unsupported features in 11 methods[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB] Detailed message:
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB] Error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved method during parsing: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.extractScalarFromObject(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer, java.lang.Class). To diagnose the issue you can use the --allow-incomplete-classpath option. The missing method is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB] Trace:
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at parsing com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.DurationDeserializer.deserialize(DurationDeserializer.java:137)
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB] Call path from entry point to com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.DurationDeserializer.deserialize(JsonParser, DeserializationContext):
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.DurationDeserializer.deserialize(DurationDeserializer.java:125)
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.DurationDeserializer.deserialize(DurationDeserializer.java:43)
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4482)
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3434)
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3402)
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at hellofx.HelloFX.deserialize(HelloFX.java:99)
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.reflect.HelloFX_deserialize_15f8adc753d5dce15c2070972d1be99d7c98ca42_239.invoke(Unknown Source)
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:224)
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:91)
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIJavaCallWrappers.jniInvoke_ARRAY:Ljava_lang_Runnable_2_0002erun_00028_00029V(generated:0)
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB] Error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved method during parsing: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.extractScalarFromObject(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer, java.lang.Class). To diagnose the issue you can use the --allow-incomplete-classpath option. The missing method is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB] Trace:
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at parsing com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.InstantDeserializer.deserialize(InstantDeserializer.java:213)
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB] Call path from entry point to com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.InstantDeserializer.deserialize(JsonParser, DeserializationContext):
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.InstantDeserializer.deserialize(InstantDeserializer.java:202)
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.InstantDeserializer.deserialize(InstantDeserializer.java:50)
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4482)
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3434)
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3402)
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at hellofx.HelloFX.deserialize(HelloFX.java:99)
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.reflect.HelloFX_deserialize_15f8adc753d5dce15c2070972d1be99d7c98ca42_239.invoke(Unknown Source)
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:224)
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:91)
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
[Thu Mar 25 10:40:26 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at
```

Here's the [full log](https://pastebin.com/PABckrEm).

I've tested the app without using 'LocalDate' and 'JavaTimeModule' and I was able to build APK and parsing also worked.

Here's the full pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>hellofx</groupId>
    <artifactId>hellofx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>HelloFX</name>

    <properties>
        <main.class>hellofx.HelloFX</main.class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>15.0.1</javafx.version>
        <javafx.maven.plugin.version>0.0.5</javafx.maven.plugin.version>
        <client.maven.plugin.version>0.1.38</client.maven.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Added jackson dependency here -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Added JavaTime data type -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${javafx.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>client-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${client.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                     <target>${client.target}</target>
                     <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>desktop</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <client.target>host</client.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>ios</id>
            <properties>
                <client.target>ios</client.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>android</id>
            <properties>
                <client.target>android</client.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

How to solve this issue?

**Update #1:-**

1. **All JSON config files are already created using 'client:runagent' goal:-**
   In the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66708097/gluon-client-plugin-unable-to-build-apk-with-jsr310-module) regarding this issue, Jose Pereda instructed me to use 'mvn client:runagent'. Since I am using Ubuntu in WSL, I've run this goal in windows command prompt and edited some config files to remove windows specific configurations.
2. **Jackson isn't causing the issue, 'JavaTimeModule' is:-**
   I've removed the LocalDate 'dob' property from 'Person' and commented out the following in HelloFX.java.
   `mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());`
   After that, I was able to build and run APK, and both serialization and deserialization worked.

And I've also tried manually adding 'reflectionconfig.json' under substrate folder as suggested by dzim. But the same issue occurs.

Comment: Short answer: You need to update your reflection config. I will try to compile a more detailed answer later. The [documentation](https://docs.gluonhq.com/) provided by Gluon goes into more detail.

Comment: Please note (because I mentioned it only briefly in my answer): You probably need to add your resources to the `pom.xml`. Some are already whitelisted by Gluon (using some wildcards), but I don't recall what all of them are. I always added everything I deemed necessary to the `resourcesList` node in the `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

Long answer for ***You need to update your reflection config.*** (since that is, what `Jackson` is doing and `GraalVM` needs to know about it, since it is *pre-compiled*).

## Documentation

Most importantly: Make sure you've read the [documentation](https://docs.gluonhq.com/) provided by Gluon.

It describes in detail, what you could do.

### `client:runagent`

The topic [client:runagent](https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_clientrunagent) describes, that you could attach GraalVM's agent to detect all reflection and so on.

I did this manually and it worked well. But it is
a) exchaustive and
b) does too much.

Gluon already prepared everything related to JavaFX, so you only need to add your specific stuff.

### Configuration

See [here](https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_configuration) to find more general details about what you need to do in case of your app needs some additional configuration.
This isn't only about reflection but anything else (target platforms, resources, platform specific build information, etc.).

### Your actual problem

#### Reflection Config

I have a little application using Jackson as well.

Under your maven resources (`src/main/resources`) add `META-INF/substrate/config`.
Add a `json` file named `reflectionconfig.json` and add the following content:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper",
    "methods": [
      { "name": "<init>", "parameterTypes": [] },
      { "name": "<init>", "parameterTypes": ["com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory"] }
    ]
  }
]
```

This tells GraalVM (I think, I'm not 100% sure about it, tbh), that it need to initialize this class and the specified methods for reflection in the resulting AOT native executable.

#### `pom.xml`

Update your `client-maven-plugin` `<configuration>` section to contain more information about the classes you want to de-/serialize with Jackson.

```xml
<configuration>
  <!-- ... main class, etc. -->

  <reflectionList>

    <!-- ... -->

    <!-- our own JSON data classes below -->
    
    <!-- more Jackson stuff -->
    <list>com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory</list>

    <!-- ... -->
  </reflectionList>
</configuration>
```

## Summary

At least im my application that's enough.

If you add dependencies like `Ikonli` you need more configs. Everything (your own code as well) that directly or indirectly uses reflection, needs to be added in the one place (reflection config) or the other (`pom.xml`).

For example: If you use FXMLs, your controller and all widgets used in the FXMLs need to be added to the `pom.xml` as well, as far as I know.

Cheers

---

## Edit on 30.03.2021

First of all: Sorry to hear that you still struggle with it. And I kinda  missed the part about the Jackson JavaTimeModule...

From another dev I once got the tipp, to add the following parameter to your native-image arguments `-H:+AllowIncompleteClasspath` (see [here](https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_nativeimageargs)).

Also the generated files sometimes need some adjustments in order for them to work: most of the time remove some links to graalvm itself, or `com.sun` stuff.
Yesterday I struggled a bit with Kotlin-Reflect and I needed to actually add some reflections and resources. This could also be the case.

I don't know if this would work, but you could try and add the mentioned method manually to the reflection config JSON:

```json
[
{
  "name":"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext",
  "methods":[{"name":"extractScalarFromObject","parameterTypes":["com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer","java.lang.Class"] }]
}
]
```

Maybe adding some resources to the JSON config might help, as well:

```
{
  "resources":{
  "includes":[
    // others
    {"pattern":"META-INF/services/.*"}
  ]},
  "bundles":[]
}
```

Why? Because there's a service loader definition in the module. See [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime/src/main/resources/META-INF/services)

But to be honest: without actually having an application where I could try that (and no, I don't try to recreate yours here), I might not be able to deliver the final missing piece...

¯\*(ツ)*/¯

Comment: Hi, I've already run 'client:runagent'. But still the issue occurs. I've tried adding the json config manually. It didn't work too. I've updated the question for more details. Please take a look.

Comment: @Manikandan see, if the edited answer could help you. Otherwise I have to say: prepare a little Repo or Gist and try to rise a **question** on GraalVMs issue tracker (on GitHub).